# Did thabet ibn qais break his wife's arm?

Tags: hadith, nikah, women, talaq, wife

In another narration of the famous hadith of first khula case says that The companion thabet ibn qais broke his wife's arm is that authentic? because in the other hadith in bukhari it seems like she praises him look at the difference:

Narrated Ibn `Abbas:

The wife of Thabit bin Qais came to the Prophet (ﷺ) and said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! **I do not blame Thabit for defects in his character or his religion**, but I, being a Muslim, dislike to behave in un-Islamic manner (if I remain with him)." On that Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said (to her), "Will you give back the garden which your husband has given you (as Mahr)?" She said, "Yes." Then the Prophet (ﷺ) said to Thabit, "O Thabit! Accept your garden, and divorce her once."

Sunan Abi Dawud 2228
Narrated Aisha, Ummul Mu'minin:

Habibah daughter of Sahl was the wife of Thabit ibn Qays Shimmas He beat her and **broke some of her part**. So she came to the Prophet (ﷺ) after morning, and complained to him against her husband. The Prophet (ﷺ) called on Thabit ibn Qays and said (to him): Take a part of her property and separate yourself from her. He asked: Is that right, Messenger of Allah? He said: Yes. He said: I have given her two gardens of mine as a dower, and they are already in her possession. The Prophet (ﷺ) said: Take them and separate yourself from her.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that he did. The first hadith only says that the wife did not **blame** him for his behavior. This does not necessarily mean that he hadn't done anything, rather maybe the wife had pardoned and dismissed it. It is also possible that he was disciplining her for a valid reason but injured her by accident while doing it - which could be why the wife did not blame him.

**Ref:**

> وهذا ظاهره أنه لم يصنع بها شيئا يقتضي الشكوى منه بسببه، لكن تقدم من رواية النسائي أنه كسر يدها، فيحمل على أنها أرادت أنه سيئ الخلق، لكنها ما تعيبه بذلك بل بشيء آخر
>
> <sup>— [Fath al-Bari](https://shamela.ws/book/1673/5489)</sup>

> قلت: جاء في رواية النسائي: أنه كسر يدها فكيف تقول لا أعتب ... الخ؟ قلت: أردت أنه سيء الخلق لكنها ما تعيبته بذلك، ولكن تعييبها إياه كان بالوجوه التي ذكرناها
>
> <sup>— [Umdat al-Qaari’](https://shamela.ws/book/5756/6150)</sup>

The report of [Sunan Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:2228) is classed as *Sahih* by [al-Albani](https://shamela.ws/book/25881/2620#p1) and *Sahih li ghayrihi* with a *Hassan* chain by [al-Arnaa’oot](https://shamela.ws/book/117359/1815#p1). The content of the hadith is also corroborated through a different chain in [Sunan Nasai](https://sunnah.com/nasai:3497). *Sahih* and *Hassan* are types of authentic ahadith.

Comment: Also possible he hit her intentionally but broke her hand by mistake and she knew it was a mistake.

Comment: @UmH               but brothers i was asking about the authenticity of the narration, is it weak or sahih?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what UmH said:

First of all, the wording in the version of Sunan Abi Dawud was criticized because there were two gardens mentioned [but in Sahih al-Bukhari there is only one garden (as mahr) mentioned.](https://shamela.ws/book/130550/642#p1)

Furthermore, the version in al-Nasaa'i is hasan, which is between weak and sahih.

Imam ash-Shawkani said that even if, for the sake of argument, he happened to break her arm, then this was not the reason for her khul'. Her reason was that she feared being ungrateful to him and falling into sin because she wouldn't be able to fulfill his rights.

Reference:

> ويعارضه ما وقع في [ ص: 294 ] حديث الربيع المذكور { أنه ضربها فكسر
> يدها } . وأجيب بأنه لم تشكه لذلك بل لسبب آخر وهو البغض أو قبح الخلقة
> كما وقع عند ابن ماجه من حديث عمرو بن شعيب عن أبيه عن جده ، وعند عبد
> الرزاق من حديث ابن عباس
>
> — [Nayl al-Awtar](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/library/content/47/2121/%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AE%D9%84%D8%B9)